# Push on Android search button with Calabash

Tags: cucumber, calabash

I have this problem: I'm testing an Android app who's using a search box embedded in an Edit Text, so it's not a typical "search" controller but in the keyboard the search button appear. I'm using Calabash to write the tests.

This is the test:

```
Scenario: Iniciar la aplicación y realizar búsquedas
 And I wait for "Música" to appear
 Then I press view with id "menu_search"
 Then I enter text "Judas Priest" into field with id "collapsibleEditText"
 Then I press "search"
```

The execution return this error:

```
And I wait for "Música" to appear
Then I press view with id "menu_search"
Then I enter text "Judas Priest" into field with id "collapsibleEditText"
Then I press "search" 
  Timeout waiting for elements: * marked:'search' (Calabash::Android::WaitHelpers::WaitError)
  features/test.feature:11:in `Then I press "search"'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the method `press_user_action_button` to press the 'search' button appearing on the keyboard. Pressing the enter key (`press_enter_key`) is not what a user would do, unless the device has a *physical* keyboard. You can read more about how Android is handling the special keyboard 'enter keys' (user action buttons) [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is the fix to the problem.

    Scenario
        .... nothing changed from the question above
        Then I press search button
        
And in the features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb

    Then /^I press search button$/ do
      press_enter_button
    end

Answer (score 0):

With the step "Then I press "search"" it will search for UI elements with that label. But that does not include the keyboard.

There are 2 options

1. Something like

   Then /^I press the enter button$/
2. Or something like this

   keyboard_enter_keyevent('KEYCODE_ENTER')

(This is copied from [Krazy Robot](http://krazyrobot.com/2014/02/calabash-android-enter-text-from-keyboard-using-adb/))

Answer (score -2):

I copy the fix to the problem.

I've create a new step definition in my scenary

```
Scenario
    .... nothing changed from the question above
    Then I press search button
```

And in the features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb

```
Then /^I press search button$/ do
  press_enter_button
end
```

And it works

Comment: The answer from Tobias R is correct.  As he mentions, you should not call press_enter_button.

Comment: It might be working, but it is not correct.  We, the maintainers of Calabash Android and Calabash iOS are telling you:  this is not the correct way to do this.